# Positioning elements relative to some ancestor but not necessarily the direct parent?

Tags: css

I needed the items in an array of elements to contain 2 things: one element that would be in the regular flow of things and another that was absolute relative to the array container. Fiddling around with position: relative/absolute/fixed, I stumbled on this:

html:

```
<div class="mainContainer">

    <div class="flexItem">
        stuff1
        <div class="itemContent" style="color:blue">
            I'm positioned absolutely, relative to the main container
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexItem">
        stuff2
        <div class="itemContent" style="color:red">
            I'm positioned absolutely, relative to the main container too!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.mainContainer {
    width:60%;
    margin-left:20%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
}

.flexItem {
    position:static;
}

.itemContent {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ruzexo2r/

Its as if an element with position:absolute has any parent with position:relative with nothing in between but position:fixed then they behave just like the absolute/relative elements were immediately related. I didn't find an explicit confirmation about this behavior though so I'm asking whether or not I can count on that to keep on working?

Comment: Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position